# Business Objects Generating Unexpected Query

Tags: business-objects

I am having problem with BusinessObject Universum and the way it generates queries and consequently yielding the results.
Here is the background: mechanism that is functioning has already been implemented. I was trying to copy the SAME mechanism just to deliver a different field.
Here is the data model: http://tinypic.com/r/ng524g/8
The mechanism that functions is marked with BLUE color. The mechanism that I tried to implement and that is not functioning is marked with RED color.

On business layer I have defined a dimension with aggregate aware function. This function takes first **VWF_Party_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD** column (at the higher level). If a user selects an attribute from contract level, function takes **VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD**  column.

Problem is when I take all attributes from VWD_Kunde_A table and than add the dimension with the mentioned aggregate aware function (ie Collectionstatus_CD), the constructed query from BO side does not make any sense. Here it is:

```
SELECT
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Namespace_TXT,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Party_KEY,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Legacy_ID
FROM
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A 
  LEFT JOIN D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Collection_A
ON D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY=D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Collection_A.Party_KEY,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A
WHERE
  (
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY=D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Party_KEY  )
AND  
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Legacy_ID  =  102241978
```

Please notice the strange conctruction in the 'FROM' part (comma has been added). Another strange and unexpected construction is in 'WHERE' part:

```
  ( D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Party_A.Party_KEY=D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Party_KEY  )
```

The mechanism that is functioning is joining joins VWD_Kunde_A with VWF_Contract_Collection_A table and yields the correct result.

Now, I have tried to define a dimension without the mentioned aggregate aware function that contains only VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD attribute. When I run the same query BO yields CORRECT results and it generates the CORRECT (expected) query.

This is the query I am expecting:

```
SELECT
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Namespace_TXT,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Party_KEY,
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Legacy_ID
FROM
D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A LEFT JOIN D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Contract_Collection_A ON D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Namespace_TXT = D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Namespace_TXT  AND  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Party_KEY = D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Party_KEY  AND  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Legacy_ID = D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Legacy_ID
WHERE
  D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWD_Kunde_A.Legacy_ID  =  102241978
```

Furthermore, I suspected that it can something to do with contexts. However, I did not find any context for the mechanism that already functions and that I tried to copy. Therefore, I did not implement any context for the mechanisam I am tring to implement.

At this point I am clueless since I tried everything I knew. I would appreciate help.

Thanks!
A.

UPDATE: it seems as aggragate aware function is not functioning... This is how it is defined:

```
@Aggregate_Aware(D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Party_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD,D_ATA_MV_FinanceTreasury.VWF_Contract_Collection_A.Collectionstatus_CD)
```

(I just copied the code from Kreditklasse and adapted it... That makes me even more confused...)

UPDATE_2: it really seems as if aggragate aware is not functioning in my case because I selected all attributes from contract_context and it still jumps to party context. Very confused because THE SAME mechasism is functioning as expected when I select Kreditklasse...

Comment: Aggregate awareness *requires* contexts. Double-check what's in place already. You may also need to configure Aggregate Navigation.

Comment: I thought about that Joe. The confusing thing in the whole story is that everything is functioning as it should with Kreditklasse. Additionaly, I did check the contextes - for Kreditklasse no contexts are defined.I also checked "Aggregate Navigation" - nothing is defined for Kreditklasse... I am looking at it over and over again, and can't find any reasonable explanation. Does anything else comes to your mind?

Comment: I also have to add that "VWF_Contract_Kreditklasse_A" and "VWF_Contract_Collection_A" tables, from my point of view do not look as the real FACT tables, beacuse as you can see both of them take all the attributes from "VWD_Kunde_A" table and just add Kreditklasse_CD and Collectionstatus_CD attributes to it, respectively. That is why I am not sure if any contexts have to be defined (after all, everything is woring as expected for Kreditklasse_CD...)

Comment: Actually, aggregate awareness does not require contexts (although they are quite often used together).  It does require Aggregate Navigation, however.

Answer (score 0):

Check the aggregate navigation.

Setting up Aggregate Awareness requires two steps (in addition to correctly defining the joins between the tables, of course):

1. Define the objects with the Aggregate_Aware function
2. Set table-object incompatibilities through Actions > Set Aggregate Navigation.

It sounds like the second part is not properly configured: make sure that any objects which require the second table are marked incompatible with the first.